# How `make_gen_block` is defined after `__init__` in the code attached?

Tags: python, class, oop, scope, pytorch

In the code below, `self.gen` is instantiated while using the `make_gen_block` function which is only defined later outside the `__init__` attribute.

How is this possible?

Shouldn't  `make_gen_block` be defined before using it to instantiate `self.gen` so when `__init__` is called, `make_gen_block` can be found within `__init__` scope?

Thanks

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
    '''
    Generator Class
    Values:
        z_dim: the dimension of the noise vector, a scalar
        im_chan: the number of channels in the images, fitted for the dataset used, a scalar
              (MNIST is black-and-white, so 1 channel is your default)
        hidden_dim: the inner dimension, a scalar
    '''
    def __init__(self, z_dim=10, im_chan=1, hidden_dim=64):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.z_dim = z_dim
        # Build the neural network
        self.gen = nn.Sequential(
            self.make_gen_block(z_dim, hidden_dim * 4),
            self.make_gen_block(hidden_dim * 4, hidden_dim * 2, kernel_size=4, stride=1),
            self.make_gen_block(hidden_dim * 2, hidden_dim),
            self.make_gen_block(hidden_dim, im_chan, kernel_size=4, final_layer=True))

    def make_gen_block(self, input_channels, output_channels, kernel_size=3, stride=2, final_layer=False):
        '''
        Function to return a sequence of operations corresponding to a generator block of DCGAN, 
        corresponding to a transposed convolution, a batchnorm (except for in the last layer), and an activation.
        Parameters:
            input_channels: how many channels the input feature representation has
            output_channels: how many channels the output feature representation should have
            kernel_size: the size of each convolutional filter, equivalent to (kernel_size, kernel_size)
            stride: the stride of the convolution
            final_layer: a boolean, true if it is the final layer and false otherwise 
                      (affects activation and batchnorm)
        '''

        #     Steps:
        #       1) Do a transposed convolution using the given parameters.
        #       2) Do a batchnorm, except for the last layer.
        #       3) Follow each batchnorm with a ReLU activation.
        #       4) If its the final layer, use a Tanh activation after the deconvolution.

        # Build the neural block
        if not final_layer:
            return nn.Sequential(
                #### START CODE HERE ####
                nn.ConvTranspose2d(input_channels, output_channels,kernel_size,stride),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(output_channels),
                nn.ReLU())
                #### END CODE HERE ####
            
        else: # Final Layer
            return nn.Sequential(
                #### START CODE HERE ####
                nn.ConvTranspose2d(input_channels, output_channels,kernel_size,stride),
                #### END CODE HERE ####
                nn.Tanh())

    def unsqueeze_noise(self, noise):
        '''
        Function for completing a forward pass of the generator: Given a noise tensor, 
        returns a copy of that noise with width and height = 1 and channels = z_dim.
        Parameters:
            noise: a noise tensor with dimensions (n_samples, z_dim)
        '''
        return noise.view(len(noise), self.z_dim, 1, 1)

    def forward(self, noise):
        '''
        Function for completing a forward pass of the generator: Given a noise tensor, 
        returns generated images.
        Parameters:
            noise: a noise tensor with dimensions (n_samples, z_dim)
        '''
        x = self.unsqueeze_noise(noise)
        return self.gen(x)

def get_noise(n_samples, z_dim, device='cpu'):
    '''
    Function for creating noise vectors: Given the dimensions (n_samples, z_dim)
    creates a tensor of that shape filled with random numbers from the normal distribution.
    Parameters:
        n_samples: the number of samples to generate, a scalar
        z_dim: the dimension of the noise vector, a scalar
        device: the device type
    '''
    return torch.randn(n_samples, z_dim, device=device)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the call to make_gen_block is actually calling `self.make_gen_block`. The `self` is important. You can see in the signature of `__init__` that `self` is injected as the first argument. The method can be referenced because `self` has been passed into the `__init__` method (so it is within the scope), and self is of type `Generator`, which has a `make_gen_block` method defined for it. The `self` instance of the class has already been constructed prior to the calling of the `__init__` method.

When the class is instantiated, the `__new__` method is called first, which constructs the instance and then the `__init__` method is called, with the new instance injected (as `self`) into the method.

Comment: Oh, I see. 
I thought __init__ was called first. 
This solves it. 
Thank you